# Nested .then and I cannot send the res.send back to the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using express.js

I have 2 API serving the same kind of data, I have a simple APP that I want to use the first one... If it return error I want to go to the next one...

The way I tried is with "nested" then:

```
app.get('/player/:userID', (req, res) =>
  fetch('https://api1.com/api/user/' + req.params.userID + '/')
  .then(function(res) {
    var contentType = res.headers.get("content-type");
    if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      apiServer = 'swgohgg';
      return res.json();
    } else {
      apiServer = 'server2';
      throw ("server 1 did not reply properly");
    }
  })
  .then(json => res.send(json))
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    if (apiServer == 'server2') {
      fetch('https://api2.com/api/user/' + req.params.userID + '/')
        .then(function(res) {
          var contentType = res.headers.get("content-type");
          if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
            return res.json();
          }
        })
        .then(json => res.end(json))
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  })
);
```

So I set the variable empty, if it fails it throws an error jump to catch, then it start the second API call, but when it send the res.send it tells me that "TypeError: res.send is not a function".

And things just goes in the wind... And I don't get any reply.

I've tried a few other things I found here but nothing seems to work... One was saying to change the "res" to result, doesn't work, pass the req also below, doesn't.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In last `then` block the `res` of `res.send`, referres to the parameter `res` of your then callback.

So it should be:

```
  .then(function() { // removed res here
    if (apiServer == 'server2') {
```

And your chaining does not do what you expect that it should too. The `then?  after the`catch`is call all the time, so if the code before the`catch`does not fail then you have two`send`.

And `apiServer` looks like a global variable, but might have multiple concurrent requests, more then one could set the `apiServer` be for it is read again.

The code should look more like this:

```
app.get('/player/:userID', (req, res) =>
  let apiServer

  fetch('https://api1.com/api/user/' + req.params.userID + '/')
  .then(function(res) {
    var contentType = res.headers.get("content-type");
    if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      apiServer = 'swgohgg';
      return res.json();
    } else {
      apiServer = 'server2';
      throw new Error("server 1 did not reply properly");
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);

    // in case of an error do a different request
    if (apiServer == 'server2') {
      return fetch('https://api2.com/api/user/' + req.params.userID + '/')
        .then(function(res) {
          var contentType = res.headers.get("content-type");
          if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
            return res.json();
          }
        })
    } else {
       throw new Error('invalid fallback server')
    }
  })
  .then(json => res.send(json))
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your variables twice in the same context/scope which is generally a bad practice. Besides, that you will end up confusing yourself and others reading your code. You can simply change the name of your variables from res to `response1` & `response2` ( just to give an idea...you can name accordingly ) to avoid shadowing. Also remove `res` from 3rd `.then`

```
app.get('/player/:userID', (req, res) =>
  fetch('https://api1.com/api/user/' + req.params.userID + '/')
  .then(function (response1) {
    var contentType = response1.headers.get("content-type");
    if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      apiServer = 'swgohgg';
      return response1.json();
    } else {
      apiServer = 'server2';
      throw ("server 1 did not reply properly");
    }
  })
  .then(json => res.send(json))
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  // removed res from argument
  .then(function () {
    if (apiServer == 'server2') {
      fetch('https://api2.com/api/user/' + req.params.userID + '/')
        .then(function (response2) {
          var contentType = response2.headers.get("content-type");
          if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
            return response2.json();
          }
        })
        //fixed res.end to res.send cause it was throwing an error
        .then(json => res.send(json))
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  })
);
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: And the `res` of `var contentType = res.headers.get("content-type")` should most certainly be `response1` and `response2`

Comment: Thats true, but what I meant is that you changed `.then(function (res) {`  to `.then(function () {`, removing that shadowing solved the problem. But you do not mention that anywhere. So without a close look to the code it is not obvious that this important change was done. It is good to change the other `res` to something different like `response1` and `response2` but those two are not the problem.

Comment: Updated . Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @HemantParashar Thanks for your input I already saw the fixed for the response1 and response2

I also edited the res.end to res.send at the end cause it was throwing an error.

It's working great!!

Thanks